# issue with handling toggles switches after deploying the production version of react node js on AWS

Tags: reactjs, node.js, amazon-web-services

now when I deploy my react nodejs project on elasticbeanstalk using the development version which I use the npm start, the project works fine and it get deployed, but I need to deploy the build (production) version, but the problem is that when deploying and opening the deployed link I can't laverage all the project features. my project should be a visualizer that visualize graph of nodes which represent organizations and the relationships between this organizations, and this relationships is determined using toggles, so with clicking each toggles the visualizer graph is being rendered to show the type of the relationships between these agencies.

so when using the build version, when clicking on the toggles the graph doesn't render (the action is not done)

this is my dockerfile for using the build version

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:12.22.9 as builder
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts -g --silent
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build

### STAGE 2: Production Environment ###
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and this is part of my package.json file for reference

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "type": "module"
```

it works and got deployed but the project visualizer rendering doesn't listen the toggles switches, However if I use the npm start on my local host or even deploying it on AWS using the npm start it works fine.

So what is the problem here because I am quite new to nodejs so I am not very aware of the framework yet.